# how setup otp(two factor authentication) on IIS( ftp server)

Tags: iis, ftp-server, one-time-password

Is there a way that we can set up One-Time-Password in iis?
As a web server is possible (via isapi) but i couldn't find As a ftp server

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/developing-for-ftp

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate how you imaging one time password with FTP?
If you care about security, you should not be using FTP at all